# Starting Android app becomes stuck for task :react-native-reanimated:downloadBoost

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, react-native-reanimated

So, I am trying to run `yarn android` in my project folder. This is not a project I made, but cloned from GitHub, and I am new to app development, so I am unfamiliar with many of the innerworkings here.

The steps I've done to get here:

1. Installed Android Studio, installed all necessary SDKs and build tools
2. Made preferred Java JDK 11
3. Cloned the repo and cd into it in the terminal
4. There was an issue happening in the past (I've tried this before and have since started from scratch) that I fixed by changing `react-native-permissions` in package.json from "^3.0.4" to to "3.8.0"
5. ran `yarn install` to install dependencies
6. ran `yarn patch-package`
7. ran `yarn android`

And while this command is running, I realize it is getting stuck at 96% execution while performing the task `:react-native-reanimated:downloadBoost` and it has been stuck this way for at least 12 or 15 minutes without any sign of progress. Below is just a snippet of the command line:

```
> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
Android gradle plugin: 4.1.0
Gradle: 6.7.1

> Task :react-native-firebase_crashlytics:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-permissions:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-iap:compilePlayDebugKotlin
w: C:\Users\lilyb\Documents\GitHub\A-Better-Meal-app\node_modules\react-native-iap\android\src\play\java\com\dooboolab\RNIap\RNIapModule.kt: (148, 77): Parameter 'outToken' is never used, could be renamed to _
w: C:\Users\lilyb\Documents\GitHub\A-Better-Meal-app\node_modules\react-native-iap\android\src\play\java\com\dooboolab\RNIap\RNIapModule.kt: (206, 40): Unnecessary safe call on a non-null receiver of type String
w: C:\Users\lilyb\Documents\GitHub\A-Better-Meal-app\node_modules\react-native-iap\android\src\play\java\com\dooboolab\RNIap\RNIapModule.kt: (444, 55): Unnecessary safe call on a non-null receiver of type String
w: C:\Users\lilyb\Documents\GitHub\A-Better-Meal-app\node_modules\react-native-iap\android\src\play\java\com\dooboolab\RNIap\RNIapModule.kt: (533, 9): Parameter 'developerPayLoad' is never used
w: C:\Users\lilyb\Documents\GitHub\A-Better-Meal-app\node_modules\react-native-iap\android\src\play\java\com\dooboolab\RNIap\RNIapModule.kt: (546, 67): There is more than one label with such a name in this scope
w: C:\Users\lilyb\Documents\GitHub\A-Better-Meal-app\node_modules\react-native-iap\android\src\play\java\com\dooboolab\RNIap\RNIapModule.kt: (563, 9): Parameter 'developerPayLoad' is never used
w: C:\Users\lilyb\Documents\GitHub\A-Better-Meal-app\node_modules\react-native-iap\android\src\play\java\com\dooboolab\RNIap\RNIapModule.kt: (677, 21): Parameter 'eventName' is never used
w: C:\Users\lilyb\Documents\GitHub\A-Better-Meal-app\node_modules\react-native-iap\android\src\play\java\com\dooboolab\RNIap\RNIapModule.kt: (682, 25): Parameter 'count' is never used

> Task :react-native-push-notification:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugJavaWithJavac


> Task :react-native-reanimated:downloadBoost
Download https://github.com/react-native-community/boost-for-react-native/releases/download/v1.63.0-0/boost_1_63_0.tar.gz
<============-> 96% EXECUTING [20m 3s]
> IDLE
> :invertase_react-native-apple-authentication:generateDebugRFile > Resolve files of :invertase_react-native-apple-authentication:debugCompileClasspath > Transform lifecycle-runtime-2.3.1.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.3.1)
> IDLE
> IDLE
> :app:mergeExtDexDevDebug
> IDLE
> :react-native-reanimated:downloadBoost > boost_1_63_0.tar.gz > 3.45 MB/11.73 MB downloaded
> IDLE
> IDLE
> :stripe_stripe-react-native:compileDebugKotlin
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
```

I tried googling this issue but I really could not find anything, and because I'm new I am really unsure how to diagnose this issue. I've tried re-doing the steps listed above after closing some background applications but no change of course. Any help is appreciated.